# Don't create a new event on eventReceive with Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm working on a page where events are creating by dragging from a list onto a full calendar object. I'm then opening a dialog (bootstrap modal) to let the user edit the event.

During the edit, they might change the date or time of the initial drop. They could also conceivably cancel the event creation.

What I'd like to do is:
Don't create the initial event and just save after the modal is responded to. That is, I'd like eventReceive to fire, so I can trap it, but not have FullCalendar add the event to the calendar.

Comment: You could slightly mis-use [dropAccept](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropAccept) and set a callback function which always return false (this preventing the event being dropped), and also initiates your modal dialog at the same time

Answer (score 2):

It's all here, just not in a 'recipe' manner: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging

Set ***create*** to false in the ***Draggable*** and handle the drag with the ***drop*** event.